# Group by ordered non-adjacent array elements in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a problem and I want to know if I can solve it in MongoDB aggregation framework or MapReduce level instead of doing it in the server code.
The problem:
I have a the following collection:

```
[
  {
    id:...,
    pages:[
       000,
       111,
       222,
       666,
       999....
    ]
  },
  {
    id:...,
    pages:[
       111,
       666,
       999....
    ]
  },
  .
  .
  .
]
```

I want to be able to ask for this path: 111, 999 and the aggregation will return count of 2, why!? because the 111 and 999 appears in two documents in this order and no matter how many elements between them.
Also I want to be able to ask for 000, 222, 999 and this will return only 1 (count) because this three array elements in this order appears only in one document.

THE ORDER is a must in my case
If I have another document with pages:[999, 666, 111] and I want to find $all 666, 999 i don't want this document to be part of the result because 999, 666 is not the same as 666, 999

Meaning that I can't sort the arrays, the order is important and I want to find arrays that contains the given elements but in this order

I hope I explained my problem properly....
What is the best way to do it in MongoDB level, is it aggregation ? or maybe map reduce or it' snot possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements.

https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/all/

```
db.Test6.count({pages: {$all: [111, 999]}}); // 2
db.Test6.count({pages: {$all: [000, 222, 999]}}); // 1
```

Related to the Ordered check, my suggestion is to suppose that the Array is already ordered (this will make the query more easy/fast to do).

In order to have the Array sorted, you should assure that when you push the element:
https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort

Comment: OK, I still have a problem here , i can't sort the arrays because 111, 999 is not the same as 999, 111. If I sort the arrays it will always be 111, 999 but that' snot right in my case.

Comment: What I actually want is the $all but considering order of elements, if I do

Comment: $all: [111, 999], should not return array with 999, 111